# Browser issue :Branching Select Drop Down Not Supporting in IE 7 or 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I have a Branching Drop down that is not working in the IE version 7 and 8 but working in all the other browsers .

Here is a js Fiddle link for live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/r64w7/

MY code :

**HTML :**

```
<div>
    <label >Select a step</label>
    <select id="selectCreateNew">
            <option value="input">
                    Input
            </option>
            <option value="radio">
                    Radio
            </option>
    </select>
</div>
   <div id="section1" style="display:none;">
      <label >Input</label>
      <input name="" type="text"/>
    </div>
   <div id="section2" style="display:none;">
         <label >Radio</label>
         <input name="" type="radio" value=""/>
   </div>
```

**javascripts**

```
var sections ={
'input': 'section1',
'radio': 'section2',
};

 selection = function(select) {

 for(i in sections)
 document.getElementById(sections[i]).style.display = "none";    
 document.getElementById(sections[select.value]).style.display = "block";

  }

  document.getElementById('selectCreateNew').addEventListener('change', function() {

  selection(this); 
try{for(var lastpass_iter=0; lastpass_iter < document.forms.length; lastpass_iter++)
   { var lastpass_f = document.forms[lastpass_iter];
     if(typeof(lastpass_f.lpsubmitorig2)=="undefined")
   { lastpass_f.lpsubmitorig2 = lastpass_f.submit; lastpass_f.submit = function()
     { var form=this; var customEvent = document.createEvent("Event");
          customEvent.initEvent("lpCustomEvent", true, true);
          var d = document.getElementById("hiddenlpsubmitdiv");
          for(var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++)

          { if(document.forms[i]==form){ d.innerText=i; } }
          d.dispatchEvent(customEvent); 
          form.lpsubmitorig2(); } } }}catch(e){}

  });
```

I am really poor in java scripts and jQuery . I got this from from my other post . I am not figuring out what is he issue for his not working in the IE 7 and 8 . Is there any way to make work this in IE 7 or 8 . If will be great if can be made support with IE 7 .

Thanks

Comment: You mentioned jQuery in the question. The code is *not* jquery, but I would strongly recommend using jquery for this, as it will make the code a lot shorter and a lot more likely to work cross-browser.

Comment: Thank you but can you give any example of that if you have ? Sorry I am not good in jquery .

Comment: Yes, sure. Have this one on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the question isn't tagged jQuery, but it was mentioned in the question, so I feel a jQuery-based answer is appropriate because this is actually *very* easy using jQuery.

Here's your HTML code. I've modified it slightly - note the changed values of the options and the extra wrapper `<div>` around the sections:

```
<div>
    <label >Select a step</label>
    <select id="selectCreateNew">
            <option value="section1">
                    Input
            </option>
            <option value="section2">
                    Radio
            </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id='sections'>
    <div id="section1" style="display:none;">
       <label >Input</label>
       <input name="" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div id="section2" style="display:none;">
         <label >Radio</label>
         <input name="" type="radio" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

..and some jQuery code to do the magic:

```
$('#selectCreateNew').change(function() {
    var showme = $(this).val();
    $('#sections>div').each(function(i,e) {
        $(e).toggle(e.id === showme);
    });
});
```

Yeah, it's as short as that.  :-)

[Here it is as a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SVgN6/)